# Symfony 6 : JSON login invalid credentials

Tags: json, symfony, security, api-platform.com

I have a problem with the JSON login of symfony.

I follow this : https://symfony.com/doc/6.3/security.html#json-login step by step but it still don't work with this message that make me crazy:

> invalid credential.

The problem is: I have some entity as `ApiResource` with API Platform. I want to make some of these resources as private: only accessible for specific roles that I choose. For that, I need to authenticate me with a JSON login, but when I try my endpoint /api/login, I have this message every time:

> "invalid credentials"

but I really test it with a special entry on my user table on my bdd, I don't understand what or where is the problem with that.

I use Symfony 6, ApiPlatform 2.7

[image: Insomnia screen]

My entity user:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 180, unique: true)]
    private string $email;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private array $roles;

    public const ARRAY_OF_ROLE = array('ROLE_IOT','ROLE_CONSUMER','ROLE_OPERATOR','ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ROLE_USER');

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     */
    #[ORM\Column]
    private string $password ;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 45)]
    private ?string $firstname = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 45)]
    private ?string $lastname = null;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(mappedBy: 'user', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private ?Operator $operator = null;



    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            if (in_array($role, self::ARRAY_OF_ROLE)) {
                $this->roles[] = $role;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname(string $firstname): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    public function setLastname(string $lastname): self
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOperator(): ?Operator
    {
        return $this->getOperator();
    }

    public function setOperator(Operator $operator): self
    {
        /*if ($this->getRoles() === ['ROLE_OPERATOR']){
            $this->operator = $operator;
        }*/
        $this->operator = $operator;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My ApiSecurityController :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Api;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Attribute\CurrentUser;

class ApiSecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/api/login', name: 'api_login'/*, methods: ['POST']*/)]
    public function login(#[CurrentUser] ?User $user): Response
    {
        if (!$user){
            return $this->json([
                'message' => 'missing credentials',
            ],
            Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        $token = 'supertoken';

        return $this->json([
            'user' => $user->getUserIdentifier(),
            'token' => $token,
        ], Response::HTTP_ACCEPTED);
    }
}
```

My security.yaml :

```
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            json_login:
                check_path: api_login
                username_path: email
                password_path: password

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/event, roles: ROLE_OPERATOR }
```

And that is my entity that I want to access only with the role that I choose:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\EventRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: EventRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'method' => 'GET',
            'path' => '/events.{_format}'
        ]
    ],
    itemOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'method' => 'GET',
            'path' => '/events/{id}.{_format}'
        ]
    ],
    attributes: [
        "security" => "is_granted('ROLE_OPERATOR')",
        'security_message' => "Seul un opérateur peut accéder à ces données."
    ],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['private']],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['public']]
)]
class Event
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 45)]
    #[Groups(['public', 'private'])]
    private string $name;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    #[Groups(['public', 'private'])]
    private \DateTimeInterface $startDate;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    #[Groups(['public', 'private'])]
    private \DateTimeInterface $endDate;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['public', 'private'])]
    private ?string $contactName = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 20, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['public', 'private'])]
    private ?string $contactPhone = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['public', 'private'])]
    private ?string $deliveryDirective = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['public', 'private'])]
    private ?int $tokensReturned = null;

    #[ORM\Column()]
    #[Groups(['public', 'private'])]
    private int $tokenProvided;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne]
    #[Groups(['public', 'private'])]
    private ?Customer $customer = null;


    #[ORM\OneToOne(inversedBy: 'eventAddress', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[Groups(['public', 'private'])]
    private ?Address $address = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'event', targetEntity: EventHasBox::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
    #[Groups(['private'])]
    private Collection $eventsHasBoxes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->eventsHasBoxes = new ArrayCollection();
    }



    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStartDate(): \DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->startDate;
    }

    public function setStartDate(\DateTimeInterface $startDate): self
    {
        $this->startDate = $startDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEndDate(): \DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->endDate;
    }

    public function setEndDate(\DateTimeInterface $endDate): self
    {
        $this->endDate = $endDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContactName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->contactName;
    }

    public function setContactName(?string $contactName): self
    {
        $this->contactName = $contactName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContactPhone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->contactPhone;
    }

    public function setContactPhone(?string $contactPhone): self
    {
        $this->contactPhone = $contactPhone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryDirective(): ?string
    {
        return $this->deliveryDirective;
    }

    public function setDeliveryDirective(?string $deliveryDirective): self
    {
        $this->deliveryDirective = $deliveryDirective;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTokensReturned(): ?int
    {
        return $this->tokensReturned;
    }

    public function setTokensReturned(?int $tokensReturned): self
    {
        $this->tokensReturned = $tokensReturned;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTokenProvided(): int
    {
        return $this->tokenProvided;
    }

    public function setTokenProvided(int $tokenProvided): self
    {
        $this->tokenProvided = $tokenProvided;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCustomer(): ?Customer
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }

    public function setCustomer(?Customer $customer): self
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAddress(): ?Address
    {
        if($this->address === null ) {
            return $this->getCustomer()->getAddress();
        }

        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setAddress(?Address $address): self
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, EventHasBox>
     */
    public function getEventsHasBoxes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->eventsHasBoxes;
    }

    public function addEventsHasBox(EventHasBox $eventsHasBox): self
    {
        if (!$this->eventsHasBoxes->contains($eventsHasBox)) {
            $this->eventsHasBoxes->add($eventsHasBox);
            $eventsHasBox->setEvent($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEventsHasBox(EventHasBox $eventsHasBox): self
    {
        if ($this->eventsHasBoxes->removeElement($eventsHasBox)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($eventsHasBox->getEvent() === $this) {
                $eventsHasBox->setEvent(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }


}
```

I try everything I see on the documentation or forum about this subject but there is nothing to do. I'm becoming crazy.

Comment: do you hash the password, or have you not got that far yet?

Comment: @Zazou  Check if the user's password is correctly hashed in the database. Try manually inserting a user record into the database.

Comment: IanMcL no hash for passwords

ŁukaszD.Tulikowski i try it but it dont work

Comment: I finally found the problem : it was a hash problem of password.

when i loadedmy fixtures, the passwords of my users fixtures dont have a hash password, and the json login system try to de-hash my password that is no hash.

Solution : hash the passwords when the fixtures load